# $exception Pseudovariable is not Available in Visual Studio Debugger (Dollar Exception)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, exception

I frequently use the [$exception pseudovariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164891.aspx) to gain access to the items in the[UpdateException.StateEntries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.updateexception.stateentries.aspx) collection as they are not accessible via the [Exception Assistant's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bc80ssc.aspx) 'View Details' dialog.

Adding a watch with the name '$exception' will return the current exception. This is also available automatically in the Locals window for C# if the exception assistant is disabled.

I have seen cases where this variable is not available. Why might this be and how can it be restored?

**Edit**: I have also posted this issue to [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/686002/no-exception-currently-available-when-using-the-exception-pseudovariable-in-the-watch-pane).

**Edit2**: The following post describes the purpose of this setting.

[Did you know? You can unwind the call stack from exceptions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2008/12/08/did-you-know-you-can-unwind-the-call-stack-from-exceptions-bill-horst.aspx)

And this one includes a couple of screenshots of the dialogs involved.

[Did you know… What unwinding the call stack on unhandled exceptions does? – #277](http://saraford.net/2008/08/08/did-you-know-what-unwinding-the-call-stack-on-unhandled-exceptions-does-277/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Debugging (General) [VS 2010]

Do you have "Unwind the call stack on unhandled exceptions" unchecked ?

It needs to be unchecked for $exception to work.

Comment: Note that the 'Unwind the call stack on unhandled exceptions' setting is a child node of 'Enable the exception assistant' which makes it easy to overlook.